# difference between syscall and kernel thread in linux and the relationship between them

Tags: linux, multithreading, kernel

I have read the book, linux kernel development, and got some problem confused me as below

1.is syscall run in kernel thread? or just run a kernel code without the form of kernel thread?
2.kernel thread and user process have different entity in schedule queue?
3.how to map user thread to a kernel thread?
4.once a process is created, the kernel thread mapped to it is created at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

syscall does not create any new threads. You are in the same user thread, but you have access also to kernel resources.
You can access to user memory directly, but should not use it. There are special macros "get_user" for user memory access.